# Is it possible to get the username from the user that pressed my inlinebutton?

Tags: telegram, aiogram

I'm trying ot create a bot that make a list of people that want to join my lessons.
As they press join i want to update the message with their username but I'm struggling to find the right way.

The only thing I found is using Aiogram's User class, but it seems not the right choice.

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['lessons'])
async def random_answer(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("...", reply_markup=keyboard_inline)
```

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text=["09:30", "18:00", "19:00", "20:00"])
async def random_value(call: types.CallbackQuery,
                       line1="Lessons\n\n09:30\n\n\n18:00\n\n\n19:00\n\n\n20:00\n\n"):
    if call.data == "09:30":
        await call.message.edit_text(line1[:13]+str(types.User.full_name)+line1[13:],
                                     reply_markup=keyboard_inline)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `call.from_user['first_name']` instead of `types.User.full_name`.